# Compare hostnames and leases between CSV and DHCP info

Tags: performance, csv, powershell

I have 3 nested loops and they do the following:

1. Get scopes from DHCP
2. Get hostnames from csv file
3. Compares hostnames and leases, matches are added to a hash table

There are 5 DHCP servers, 100's of scopes and thousands of leases.

What would be a good method to speed this up?

```
$DHServers = Get-DhcpServerInDC #get DHCP info
$hashtable = @{} #create hash table

foreach ($server in $DHServers){
$scopes = Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server.dnsname #get all scopes in DHCP   
    
    foreach ($_ in (Import-Csv C:\script\Asset_List.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty asset)){ #get hostnames from list          
        
        foreach ($scope in $scopes){            
            if($scope | Get-DhcpServerV4Lease -ComputerName $server.dnsname | Where-Object HostName -like "$_*" ){ #compares the hostname to find which lease it is in
                $scopename=$scope.name #matches give scope name
                $hashtable[$_] = $scopename #when a match is found, add keys and values to table
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/259596/2) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Why do you `Import-Csv` _inside_ the `foreach ($server in $DHServers)` loop? Do it once and save to a variable _Before_ the loop. File manipulation is always time consuming… Moreover, the `foreach ($_ in …` seems to be a nonstandard construct, see difference between `foreach` and `Foreach-Object`. Read _entire_ [about_foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7) topic.

Comment: Doing it inside vs outside only took a few milliseconds off. Its calling DHCP info each time I loop that is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping the DHCP calls through `foreach-object` instead and then comparing at the end, cut the time down from 3min to 1min. Everything I have read made it seem like `foreach` was faster. Having DHCP being processed down the pipe with `foreach-object` instead of several iterations with `foreach` makes `foreach-objects` more efficient.

````
$servers = Get-DHCPServerInDC
$hashtable = @{}

# scopes into the leases to go into the PsCustomObject to be matched later
$leases = $servers | ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_.dnsname
    Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -computerName $server  #get scopes on DHCP serves
    
    } | ForEach-Object {
    $scope = $_
    $_ | Get-DHCPServerV4Lease -ComputerName $server | #get leases in all the scopes
    
     ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{ # Make object to match later
        ScopeName = $scope.name #want name of scope only
        HostName  = $_.hostname #want hostname of leases
        }
    }
}



$assets = (Import-CSV c:\script\Asset_List.csv).asset #pull asset list
 
$assets | ForEach-Object { $asset = $_ #Go through hostnames finding matching lease

    $leases | Where-Object { #check leases
        $_.HostName -like "${asset}*" #find hostname 
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $hashtable[$asset] = $_.ScopeName #store matches
    }
}
```
````